# Using AmpScript to populate the number of days in a month

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to populate the last day of the month for the current month in the email.

Here is what I have so far.  **I am getting errors.**

```
%%[ VAR @lastdaymonth

 SET @lastdaymonth = xtmonthnumeric]%%

 %%[ if %%= v(@lastdaymonth) =%% == "1" then ]%% 

January 31 

%%[ elseif %%= v(@lastdaymonth) =%% == "2" then ]%% 

February 28 

%%[ else %%= v(@lastdaymonth) =%% == "3" then ]%% 

March 31

etc.....

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange! Your question may be easier to answer if you also update it with the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that shows the last day of any current month:

```
%%[ <br/>
set @firstday=Format(concat(DatePart(Now(),"month"),"/01/",DatePart(Now(),"year")),"MM/dd/yy")<br/> set @nextmonth = DateAdd(@firstday,"1","M") <br/>
set @lastday = Format(DateAdd(@nextmonth,"-1","D"),"MM/dd/yy") <br/>
]%% <br/>
<br/>
%%=v(@firstday)=%% and ends %%=v(@lastday)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

AMPScript blocks cannot be nested, so if there is a need to reference a variable just use the variable name, it does not need to be wrapped in %%=v()=%%, please try:

```
%%[ VAR @lastdaymonth

 SET @lastdaymonth = xtmonthnumeric]%%

 %%[ if @lastdaymonth == "1" then ]%% 

January 31 

%%[ elseif @lastdaymonth == "2" then ]%% 

February 28 

%%[ else @lastdaymonth == "3" then ]%% 

March 31

etc.....

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

K-grifin,
Your answer was very helpful as I needed to display a coupon code expiration date, expiring on the last day of the following month.  All that was necessary was a slight change to the code you provided in order to achieve that goal.

Thanks,
Steve

```
%%[
set @firstday=Format(concat(DatePart(Now(),"month"),"/01/",DatePart(Now(),"year")),"MM/dd/yy")
set @skipmonth = DateAdd(@firstday,"2","M")
set @expday = Format(DateAdd(@skipmonth,"-1","D"),"MM/dd/yy")
]%%

%%=v(@expday)=%%
```